# looping a function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
setTimeout(bye,2000)}

console.log("asda")

function bye(){
  console.log("gudbye")
}
```

I want the program to log bye once evey 2 second,but this works just for the fist log, so i get instantly 5 time "gudbye" in 2 seconds

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to execute code periodically.

Comment: `setTimeout()` doesn't wait, it just schedules the function to run in 2 seconds then returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```js
setInterval(bye,2000)

function bye(){
  console.log("gudbye")
}
```

setInterval will run your function every 2 seconds, instead of running just one time after 2000 seconds per call.

but if you only want it to be called 5 times you can try the recursive aproach:

```js
bye(1)
function bye(callCount){
  console.log("gudbye")
  if(callCount < 5){
      setTimeout(() => bye(callCount+1), 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: But it also never stops. Whereas original poster wanted to run 5 times.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original poster only wants 5 times, but if its the case, it can be changes to something like:

bye(0)

function bye(callCount){
  console.log("gudbye")
  if(callCount < 5){
      setTimeout(() => bye(callCount+1), 2000);
  }
}